# PDO devolvendo erro quando não há erro

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ubuntu, linux

De forma aleatória, eu recebo o seguinte erro ao atualizar meu sistema:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Cannot assign requested address
```

Pelo erro, ele não consegue conectar ao servidor, mas o servidor está lá, e está on, com certeza absoluta disso, pois em outros PC's quando da esse erro no meu, em outros continua normalmente.

Não tem padrão pra isso acontecer, é sem motivo nenhum, as vezes quando atualizo minha página, ou faço alguma requisição via ajax, o PHP me retorna esse erro, não é preciso fazer nada, apenas atualizar uma ou duas (as vezes bem mais) que ele volta a funcionar normalmente.

Detalhe, isso ocorre com mais frequencia no meu PC de produção (com ubuntu 16.4) , no meu teste (Win 7) ocorre raramente.

Esse sistema está em um servidor interno (Debian 7), a rede possui proxy e firewall, mas meus PC's de desenvolvimento não passam por nenhum dos dois.

Já estou com esse problema chato a alguns dias, qualquer sugestão é bem vinda pois ja tentei tudo que eu pude pensar.

OBS: Meu banco de dados é relativamente grande.

O código de conexão é o mais básico possível:

```
namespace MySQL;
class MySQLConector {

    /**
     * Receber a conexão
     * @return \PDO
     */
    public static function get_conn() {
        $database_url = '192.168.0.254';
        $database = 'database';
        $database_user = 'user';
        $database_pass = 'password';
        $PDO = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $database_url . ';dbname=' . $database . '', $database_user, $database_pass);
        $PDO->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");
        //$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $PDO;
    }

}
```

Comment: O número de requisições ao sistema é grande? Pode ser que o servidor não está suportando tratar de todas ao mesmo tempo. De qualquer forma, acredito ser interessante você colocar o código na pergunta.

Comment: A quantidade não é muita, mas o que algumas solicitações fazem são coisas grandes, mas é um servidor dedicado, esse erro é a primeira coisa do sistema, ele nem chega a fazer as requisições mais pesadas quando acontece isso, nem a requisição de login ele consegue fazer quando aparece o erro